# How to open clustered markers on certain zoom level

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility. When I change zoom level to highest, I want to show all markers without any clusters. But when I decrease zoom level markers, shout became to clusters again. I don't know how to cluster/decluster markers on certain zoom level.

Comment: It is probably not a very good idea to cluster/decluster on certain zoom level, when you decluster, your map camera might need to change the zoom level to fit all declustered markers, which will fire the `onCameraChange()` callback again. But if you want to decluster, you can see [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30706629/4195406) for details about how to decluster a single cluster. Alternatively, you can call the [clearItems()](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.html#clearItems--) at certain zoom level.

Comment: This answer may help for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267775/clustering-map-markers-on-zoom-out-and-unclustering-on-zoom-in/39845179#39845179

Comment: Please refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41291600/5796780)